# Loop and end of simple calculator on a specific condition

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and I've been having some trouble figuring this out.
I finished this simple calculator but i need to add two specific conditions on it.

*First, I need it to loop after finishing if the first input is a number.

*Second, I need the program to end if the first input is a non-number.

How would i go about this?
Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
float num_1,num_2;


char operator_1;

cout << "Enter a number, an operator, and another number: " << endl;
cin >> num_1;
cin >> operator_1;
cin >> num_2;


cout << num_1 << " ";
cout   << operator_1 << " ";
cout  << num_2 << " = ";


switch (operator_1) 
{
    case '+':
        cout << num_1 + num_2;
        break;
    case '-':
        cout << num_1 - num_2;
        break;
    case '*':
        cout << num_1 * num_2;
        break;
    case '/':
        cout << num_1 / num_2;
        break;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Figure out what part of your program should repeat and put that inside the loop.

Comment: Unrelated: You should test all of the inputs to make sure they make sense. For example what will your program do if if `num_1` is a valid number and `num_2` isn't?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
int main()
{
    float num_1, num_2;
    char operator_1;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter a number, an operator, and another number: " << endl;
        if (!(cin >> num_1)) {

            cout << "Error" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        cin >> operator_1;
        cin >> num_2;


        cout << num_1 << " ";
        cout << operator_1 << " ";
        cout << num_2 << " = ";


        switch (operator_1)
        {
        case '+':
            cout << num_1 + num_2 << endl;
            break;
        case '-':
            cout << num_1 - num_2 << endl;
            break;
        case '*':
            cout << num_1 * num_2 << endl;
            break;
        case '/':
            cout << num_1 / num_2 << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note how the error in `num_1` is caught and how everything is inside a `while` loop. The program will only end if the first input is not valid, as you wanted.